# join() function php to array

Tags: php, xml, arrays, join

I need to put xml into array and then use join function to show xml file 
I extract already xml but don't know how to use join function for this code. 
Please help me to figure out this.
Here is xml code:

```
<ValCurs Date="06.07.2012" name="Ratele oficiale de schimb">
<Valute ID="47">
<NumCode>978</NumCode>
<CharCode>EUR</CharCode>
<Nominal>1</Nominal>
<Name>Euro</Name>
<Value>15.3051</Value>
</Valute>
<Valute ID="44">
<NumCode>840</NumCode>
<CharCode>USD</CharCode>
<Nominal>1</Nominal>
<Name>Dolar S.U.A.</Name>
<Value>12.2343</Value>
```

Function to extraxt xml :

```
function curs() {
  $date = date("d.m.Y");  
  $link = 'http://bnm.md/md/official_exchange_rates?get_xml=1&date='.$date; 
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $xml_array = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  $xml_array = file_get_contents($link);

    $values = array();

 $curs = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_array);

 foreach($curs as $key => $value) {

    if (($value->CharCode) == 'USD') {

    $values .= $value->Name." - ".$value->Value.", ";
    }

    if (($value->CharCode) == 'EUR') {

        $values .= $value->Name." - ".$value->Value.", ";
    }
  }

  $value = str_replace(',', '.', $values);

   return $value;
}
```

Comment: For `join()` (aka `implode()`) you need an array - you're not producing one, so you have nothing to implode.

Comment: how can I do that? 
can you help me please

Comment: Here is what I need to do, create an array: $allowed_currencies = array(‘EUR’, ‘USD’) 
and insted of 
if (($value->CharCode) == 'USD') {
if (($value->CharCode) == 'EUR') {

to check and extract USD and EUR from $allowed_currencies

Comment: I read that already, but anyway is hard for me to understand that :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not overly clear what you are asking for, but if I gather it correctly you want to do something like this. Note you were mixing array and string logic for the variable $values.

```
$values = array();
$curs = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_array);

foreach($curs as $key => $value) {

    if (($value->CharCode) == 'USD') {

        $values[] = $value->Name." - ".$value->Value;
    }

    if (($value->CharCode) == 'EUR') {

        $values[] = $value->Name." - ".$value->Value;
    }
}

$value = implode('.', $values);

return $value;
```

Note: I'm not sure on the usefulness of merging these strings with "." i'd expect you'd be after something like \n.